# PHP submit to self form

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to create a login page and have it to submit to itself and then redirect based on if user is authenticated. But for some reason everytime i submit, with wrong username or password, i would like it to show the log in screen again but it just shows blank. But if i login correctly then it works.

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST)){ 

require_once 'includes/db.php';

    if($user->login($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]))
        echo "user is logged in";   
}else{
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>User name:</td>
        <td>Password: </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `!empty($_POST)` clause triggers because the `$_POST` variable isn't empty, as you just send some login credentials (they may be wrong but that doesn't matter).

The `else` clause just triggers when nothing is sent, so basically whenever you submit **anything** with the form, if the login credentials are right `user is logged in` will appear and if they are wrong, nothing will be put out whatsoever.

The easiest way to solve this would be to remove the `else` clause entirely and add `exit()` into the `if` clause checking the credentials like so:

```
<?php 
    if (!empty($_POST)) { 
        require_once 'includes/db.php';

        if ($user->login($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"])) {
            echo "user is logged in";

            /* Add exit() if you don't want the form to show
               up when login attempt was successful. */
        }
    }
?>

<!-- HTML CODE -->
```

Answer (score 0):

check the syntax correctly...

```
if($user->login($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]))
{
        //if login success, then redirect to index.php
        header('Location:index.php');
}else{
        //if username and pass do not match or login fails, redirect to login.php

?>
```